# CSS - Dropbox website footer effect?

Tags: html, css

See dropbox's site here: https://www.dropbox.com

Notice how the footer "Learn more" **stays at the bottom** until you click or scroll down, no matter how much you resize the window?

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
```

Above is CSS for the footer part but thats not causing the effect.

How can this effect be achieved, I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You missed a semi-colon at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about that front page that always fills the whole browser window with the "learn more" sticking to the bottom of the window?

There are multiple ways to do this, here's one:

Put your first page in a `<div>` (or any other container) and set it's height to `100vh`, which will always resize to the height of your browser window (100% of the *view height*).

The link "Learn more" is then simply attached using `position: absolute;`.

The following pages can then take any height, although you can use the same technique to make pages you can scroll through (similar to a slideshow).

[You can try it using this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Smaxx/9k19mtz9/)

Answer (score 1):

Position:fixed is what you want, not absolute.

Comment: although i don't see the position:fixed; attribute on dropbox for that footer part. how are they doing it?